# Sencha Ext.Loader.setPath() is undefined

Tags: extjs, cmd

When I use sencha CMD (I have tried 4 and 5 with similar results), I get an error on loading app like:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setPath' of undefined
```

This error is referring to: Ext.Loader.setPath(), but also fires on Ext.application, and Ext.Loader.setConfig( if I re-order them.

There are no errors before or after this, it loads fine when loading without building, produces same results with production and development microloaders.

Any thoughts?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html manifest="" lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script id="microloader" type="text/javascript" src="touch/microloader/development.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function init() {
            document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
        }
        function onResume() {

        }
    </script>   
</head>
<body onload="init()">
    <img id='splashImage' src='resources/images/splash.png' />
    <img id="splashLogo" src='resources/images/splashLogo.png' />
    <div id="appLoadingIndicator">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm also having this issue. Did you ever resolve it?